# Sharepoint Custom Field

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

I've created a custom field type, I think there are no mistakes, becouse it's so simple, but the field box is not displayed at the form (see pic.)

[image: pic]

.ascx file:

```
 <SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="MyField" runat="server">
 <Template>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextField" MaxLength="255" runat="server" BackColor="Pink"
 Font-Bold="true" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderColor="DarkBlue" TextMode="MultiLine" />
 </Template>
 </SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

Field Type file:

```
namespace MyCustomField.CustomField
{
class SPFieldMyCustomField : SPFieldMultiLineText
{

    public SPFieldMyCustomField(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName) : base(fields, fieldName)
    {
    }

    public SPFieldMyCustomField(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName)
        : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
    {
    }

    public override BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
    {
        get
        {
            BaseFieldControl control = new MyCustomFieldControl();
            control.FieldName = base.InternalName;

            control.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;

            return control;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and Control file:

```
namespace MyCustomField.CustomField
{
internal class MyCustomFieldControl : RichTextField
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        var html = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item[Field.InternalName] as string) ? "" : Item[Field.InternalName] as string;

        RenderHtmlForDisplay(output, html);
    }

    protected override string DefaultTemplateName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyField"; 
        }
    } 
}
}
```

As you can see TextBox isn't displayed.

Comment: For SharePoint related questions, you have http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the control is setup to only render for `SPControlMode.Display`. Your screenshot is showing in `Edit` or `New` mode

It looks like you'll want to override the [RenderFieldForInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.richtextfield.renderfieldforinput.aspx) method

```
protected override void RenderFieldForInput(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    var html = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item[Field.InternalName] as string) ? "" : Item[Field.InternalName] as string;

    RenderHtmlForDisplay(output, html);
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you, I copypasted this part of code, and didn't know what does it mean. Thank you.